# Pentaho Data Integration which generic driver with OpenEdge database

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I am trying to use the generic pentaho driver (PDI) to connect on an OpenEdge database. When I was using the PDI trial, I was connecting normally, but when the test time was over and I went to open the same project with a community section, it doesn’t work at all, I’ve tried to register the open jar several times warranty and nothing so far.

Error:

> Driver class 'com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Generic database' driver (jar file) is installed.
> com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver

I already tried to contact Hitachi to buy the license, but it is very expensive for a developer alone to pay. In case anyone has an idea of ​​what to do, I'm desperate, because my projects are using pdi for ETL.

Comment: have you downloaded community version of pentaho data integration?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it from the sourceforge website.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the openedge.jar driver file to your data-integration/lib folder.
The jar file itself is available from https://www.progress.com/odbc/openedge.